# Two array with same index key and structure need single array of combine array of it

Tags: php, arrays

**My First Array Look Like This**

`$array1 = array('0' => 'news', '1' => 'game');`

```
Array
(
    [0] => news
    [1] => game
)
```

**My Second Array Look Like This**

`$array2 = array('0' => '1', '1' => '2');`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

**I Need Output Like This**

```
$array3 = array(array('0'=>'new', '1'=>'1'),array('0'=>'game', '1'=>'2'));

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => new
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => game
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

I tried multiple way using array_merge, array_merge_recursive and loop
 but not getting the proper output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy way:

```
$result = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);
```

This will work regardless of the indexes, so in your case, for better or worse, these would also produce the same result:

```
$array1 = array(1 => 'news', 5 => 'game');
$array2 = array(2 => '1', 6 => '2');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for this, with `null` as first argument:

```
$result = array_map(null, $first_array, $second_array);
```

Comment: Great, Thankyou so much it works for me..its really helpful

Answer (score 0):

use this [code](https://www.tehplayground.com/Z7um7Shr97YYMvRm)

```
$array1 = array_values($array1);
$array2 = array_values($array2);
$array = [];

$count = count($array1);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    $array[] = [$array1[$i] , $array2[$i]];

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of ways to do this, array_map as other's have answered is probably your best bet. IF you want to see what's happening:

```
 foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
      $array3[$key] = array($value, $array2[$key]);
 }
```